# Help with running two Images at the same time

Tags: raspbian, pi-4

So I bought the Rasberry PI intending to run Homebridge and eBlocker. I'm new to this theme, but I can only run one image at a time when I understand it correctly. Is there an option on how to run both of them on the Raspberry at the same time?

I have installed the standard Raspery Desktop OS till now.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What is Homebridge?  What is eBlocker?  Edit the information into your question.  Perhaps if we know what they are it would be possible to answer the question.